# PDF Generator identification

Tags: parsing, pdf, signature

What's the best way to identify the generator / detect the schema of an automatically generated PDF ?
I've being using Tabula & Textual analysis for extracting datas once the file is identified, but I'm struggling to dispatch the file to the correct parser.
Obviously, the PDFs have no metadatas regarding the author, and the file name can be changed and therefore is not an accurate source of identification.

Thanks,
Arthur

Comment: Essentially you can only look for individual, specific fingerprints in the PDFs from the respective sources. They might be combinations of facts like which end-of-line is used, where special objects (in particular the catalog or the info dictionary) are located in the file, which kinds of objects are indirect and which are not, ...

Comment: According to you, can it be realistically automatically inferred with let's say 10 cases per type and a huge amount of PDF types ? For now, forgetting the automatic part, I'm going the PDFtoText & regex route, which did the trick for all tested cases. Any better/faster idea ? Thanks !

Comment: I assume it could be done but it would require a lot of initial work to find those fingerprints.

Comment: Ok, guess I'll stick to regexes then, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the trailer:

```
trailer
<<
/Size 9
/Root 1 0 R
/Info 8 0 R
>>
startxref
626
%%EOF
```

... and scan for `/Info`. There will be a `8 0`(in this case) section containing the meta data, e.g.

```
8 0 obj
<<
/Creator (PDFDUMP WIN32 )
/CreationDate (D:20201231000000)
>>
endobj
```

But it would become more complicated when the metadata section is not straight forward (e.g. containing hexadecimal code, or indirectly point to another section).

It becomes tricky when the meta data is like this:

```
42 0 obj
(git-cheat-sheet-education)
endobj
43 0 obj
(Mac OS X 10.9.1 Quartz PDFContext)
endobj
44 0 obj
(Adobe Illustrator CC \(Macintosh\))
endobj
45 0 obj
(D:20140224195805Z00'00')
endobj
1 0 obj
<< /Title 42 0 R /Producer 43 0 R /Creator 44 0 R /CreationDate 45 0 R /ModDate
45 0 R >>
endobj
```

There are quite a number of open-source code which can display the PDF meta data for you.

I am not sure if I am answering your question.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for taking the time to answer. Sadly, as stated in the question, due to the fact that people don't often sign their PDF, and the solution requiring an "universal" scenario, it can't be used.
To give an example of the need, let say you have 30 people sending generated bills: Each one has it's schema. If you know it and learn from it, you just have to handle 30 cases, and the parsing with 100% accuracy is done with a simple drag&drop without any specification.
For now my best solution is a PDFtoText and then a regex for each generator.